# Compare-Object and include properties not being compared in output

Tags: powershell, csv, compareobject

I'm comparing two CSV files that come from different sources (different column/property names) using the `Compare-Object` cmdlet. How can I include properties that are in either CSV file in the output without including them in the comparison?

Example CSV data

**users1.csv**

```
e-mail-address,name,side
luke@sw.com,Luke,light
```

**users2.csv**

```
e-mail-address,hiredate,hobbies
lando@sw.com,5/2/17,Sabacc
```

The following gives me a column with the e-mail address and side indicator, but how can I get `$Users1.name` and `$Users2.hiredate` without using them in the comparison?

```
$Users1 = Import-Csv users1.csv
$Users2 = Import-Csv users2.csv

Compare-Object $Users1 $Users2 -Property "E-mail-Address"
```

I'd like output similar to:

```
e-mail-address | SideIndicator | name | hiredate
---------------|---------------|------|----------
luke@sw.com    | <=            | Luke |
lando@sw.com   | =>            |      | 5/2/17
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `PassThru` parameter to have `Compare-Object` return all the properties, then use `Select-Object` to grab the `name` and `hiredate` properties:

```
Compare-Object $users1 $users2 -Property e-mail-address -PassThru|Select-Object e-mail-address,SideIndicator,name,hiredate
```